# statement result as string compare error in Linux

Tags: string, bash, shell

I wrote a piece of code to check if target is occupied, and here is the code:

```
board_status=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 root@10.31.35.84 -t "cat /userdata/status" )
echo board_status: $board_status 

if [[ $board_status == "BUSY" ]]; then
    echo board is busy
    EVAL_BOARD_IP=0
else
    echo board is not busy
    EVAL_BOARD_IP=10.31.35.84
fi
echo EVAL_BOARD_IP: ${EVAL_BOARD_IP}
```

I found it does not work, and the printed result is:

```
$ sh test.sh
Connection to 10.31.35.84 closed.
board_status: BUSY
board is not busy
EVAL_BOARD_IP: 10.31.35.84
```

I can't figure out why the if statement will go to the else branch

Comment: Since the code asks for `$board_status` to be _equal_ to `BUSY`, not just contain it, there is a possibility that non-visible characters (such as blanks or carriage returns) prevent equality.  Run `declare -p board_status` and tell us what it shows.

Comment: Alternatively, try `if [[ $board_status =~ "BUSY" ]]; then` in place of `if [[ $board_status == "BUSY" ]]; then`

Comment: @John1024  I've tried it outside in the terminal, and here is the result : 
 $ ss=$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 root@10.31.35.84 -t "cat /userdata/status" )
Connection to 10.31.35.84 closed.
$ declare -p ss
"eclare -- ss="BUSY

Comment: Changing it to  ` if [[ $board_status =~ "BUSY" ]]; then ` worked for me. Although I still can not figure out why...

Comment: So, as shown, the final `"` is missing from the `declare -p` output, correct?

Comment: @John1024 the output is : "eclare -- ss="BUSY

Comment: the " symbol is actually at the beginning

Comment: That explains it.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
if [[ $board_status == "BUSY" ]]; then
```

with

```
if [[ $board_status =~ "BUSY" ]]; then
```

The first command tests whether `$board_status` is *equal* to `BUSY`.  The latter tests whether `$board_status` simply contains the characters `BUSY`

#### What went wrong.

Suppose the file `/userdata/status` has DOS/Windows line endings, meaning that `board_status` will have a final carriage return character, `\r`, like this:

```
 board_status=$'BUSY\r'
```

With this value, observe what the `declare -p` output looks like:

```
$ declare -p board_status
"eclare -- board_status="BUSY
```

This is because the carriage return after the `Y` causes the terminal to start writing from the beginning of the line, overwriting the `d` with what should have been the final character on the line, `"`.

If `board_status` was actually `BUSY`, this is what the `declare -p` command should look like:

```
$ board_status=$'BUSY'
$ declare -p board_status
declare -- board_status="BUSY"
```